# Zend Form validation not working properly

Tags: forms, validation, zend-framework

I have created this phone form input field for Zend Framework. It's supposed to ensure that the input is exactly 10 numeric digits. But it fails validation when given the proper input. Can anyone please tell me why?

```
<?php 
class Form_uspsSettings extends Zend_Form
{
. . .
      $phone = $this->createElement('text','phone');
        $phone->setLabel('Phone: *')
              ->setRequired(true)
              ->addFilter('Digits')
          ->addValidators(array(
            array('Digits'),
            array('stringLength', false, array(10))
          ));
```

Comment: I think your stringLength validator needs two values: min & max. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.stringlength

Comment: I tried it with two values but that made no difference. I did see somewhere in the docs where they supplied a single value, so I think that is valid. Thanks for the observation though.

Answer (score 0):

This is The Correct way ,

```
        'validators' => array(
            array('StringLength', false, array(10, 10)),
        ),
```

just give it two values as dirk suggested .. it will surely work..

Comment: I'll try again and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I even changed my 'stringLength' to upper-case 'S' just in case. No joy.

Comment: does it fire any exception ? or it just takes any number characters ?

Comment: It fails validation even with exactly 10 characters. I passed this problem on to a colleague so I can work on other things.